# In Android Chromium, build failed due to xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError

Tags: java, android, chromium

***Traceback (most recent call last):***

```
  File "../../build/android/gyp/write_build_config.py", line 750, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "../../build/android/gyp/write_build_config.py", line 688, in main
    manifest = AndroidManifest(options.android_manifest)
  File "../../build/android/gyp/write_build_config.py", line 48, in __init__
    dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1918, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 924, in parse
    result = builder.parseFile(fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 207, in parseFile
    parser.Parse(buffer, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 118, column 8
```

**[3/132] ACTION //chrome/android:chrome_java_resources(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.**

**EDIT**

***history_row.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_url"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:textColor="#990000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

***UrlHisLA.java***

*only Method not entire class, which the error was shown*

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (inflater == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_row, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.tv_url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_url);
            viewHolder.tv_time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
            viewHolder.parent_layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.tv_url.setText(history.get(position).getUrl());
        viewHolder.tv_time.setText(history.get(position).getTime());
        return convertView;
    }
```

Error which i got earlier which is suddenly disappeared and now suddenly build is getting stopped.

Error :

**../../chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/..../UrlHisLA.java:59: error: cannot find symbol**

```
 convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_row, null);
                                       ^
```

*symbol: variable history_row location: class layout*

**../../chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/..../UrlHisLA.java:61: error: cannot find symbol**

```
viewHolder.tv_url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_url);
                                                        ^
```

*symbol: variable tv_url location: class id*

**../../chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/..../UrlHisLA.java:62: error: cannot find symbol**

```
viewHolder.tv_time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
                                                             ^
```

*symbol: variable tv_time location: class id*

**../../chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/..../UrlHisLA.java:63: error: cannot find symbol**

```
viewHolder.parent_layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
                                                                       ^
```

*symbol: variable parent_layout location: class id*

**../../chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/..../SSLTM.java:122: error: cannot find symbol**

```
InputStream inStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.tmt);
                                                               ^
```

*symbol: variable raw location: class R*

**../../chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/..../SSLTM.java:140: error: cannot find symbol**

```
InputStream stream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.tmt_keystore);
                                                             ^
```

*symbol: variable raw location: class R*

***6 errors***

Comment: Please paste the xml file causing this error, most probably it's invalid.

Comment: @the-dagger Edited with necessary file which you asked.

Comment: Hey Sandeep, do you have all the necessary dependencies setup to build chromium?
Also may I ask which link are you following to build it?

Comment: @the-dagger It worked with the older version of the chromium but on the latest version it is not working and yeah, i have all the dependencies to build the chromium.

In ubuntu, using this [link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md#Build-the-full-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there is some commented code inside the opened tag so this was problem which population, found it use **git diff** if you understand what i'm talking